# How can fix the random effects structure or the tolerances of my glmmTMB model so I can obtain a warning free R^2?

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I'm running a model where I test the effects of environmental variables on the number of inflorescences of a plant. I have three years of data from twelve different sites for ~ 600 individuals.

- My environmental variables: **heat, area and year** are the fixed effects, all scaled
- My random effects are **sites, transects and plant_id**

The model looks like this:

```
my_model<- glmmTMB(inflorescences ~ heat + area + year +
(1 | site_id/trans_id/plant_id), data= alldatjoin5, REML = FALSE, control=glmmTMBControl(optCtrl=list(iter.max=1e3,eval.max=1e3), optimizer = nlminb),family = poisson(link = log))
```

Summary looks good, but when I run performance::r2(my_model) it give back the warnings:

```
1: Can't compute random effect variances. Some variance components equal zero. Your model may
  suffer from singularity (see `?lme4::isSingular` and `?performance::check_singularity`).
  Solution: Respecify random structure! You may also decrease the `tolerance` level to enforce
  the calculation of random effect variances. 
2: mu of 1.1 is too close to zero, estimate of random effect variances may be unreliable.
```

I want to:

- Decrease the tolerance levels as first measure. As I cannot see a better way to re-specify the random structure.

Thanks for the insight you can provide!